# Java and Selenium - select radio button in list by text

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to select entries in a list by the text. The li entries also have id's, but I'd like to use the text instead.

I've got the following html snippet:

```
<fieldset felt id="bosted"
  <ul class="feltliste ng-scope">
    <li> 
      <label id="lblbostedleierKommunalt" for="bostedleierKommunalt" class="label ">
         Leier kommunal bolig
      </label>
    </li>(verdi, tekst) in bostedTyper -->
    <li>
      <label id="lblbostedleierPrivat" for="bostedleierPrivat" class="label ">
         Leier bolig
        <div class="hjelpetekst ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-class="{'hjelpetekst--utvidet': visHjelpetekst}" id="leierPrivat-hjelpetekst " ng-if="verdi === 'LEIER_PRIVAT'">
          <button title="Vis hjelpetekst" type="button" ng-click="visEllerSkjulHjelpetekst($event)" aria-describedby="leierPrivat-hjelpetekst ">
          <span class="bare-skjermleser" translate=""><span class="ng-scope">Vis hjelpetekst</span></span>
          <est-ikon type="sporsmalstegn"><svg focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#ikon-sporsmalstegn"></use></svg>
        </div>
```

The text entries in the above example are

Leier kommunal bolig
Leier bolig

**Option 1:** I'm trying to do it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id='bosted' li[text=" + text + "]")).click();
```

I've tried "value" and other options. But I keep getting "An invalid or illegal selector was specified".

**Option 2:** I've also tried this solution, taken from an answer to a similar question in here:

```
List<WebElement> options = bosted.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
        if (option.getText().equals(bosituasjon)) {
                option.click();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Except that I think it looks messy and not very elegant, it doesn't work either. When watching the test rund, it seems like it tries to click an entry above the target entry on the page. (Although I'm not sure about that.) It returns no error, though.

However, it does find all the text entries, and the if loop hits and executes the option.click() line.

But something is clearly wrong, as it doesn't navigate to the list entry on the page, and the option is not selected.

Also, if I use .sendkeys(Keys.ENTER) instead of .click(), I get an "element not interactable" error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` in your selector, not `text`.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id='bosted' li[value=" + text + "]")).click();
```

Anyway, you can you use [XPath](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) selector that uses id inside.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id = 'bosted']/descendant::li[text() = '" + text + "']")).click();
```

Comment: I really don't like XPath, since it's not a stable part of the page like id tags.

Comment: Updated answer, try with value

Comment: My bad. value was the first thing I tried. text was the next. Value results in the same error (invalid or illegal selector). There is no value attribute for that entry; There is one for the parent tag, but since I need to use the text, the value is not applicable.

Comment: The xpath method results in: "This results in "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[contains(text(),'Leier kommunal bolig')]"}

Comment: hey, my approach is different, see above.

Comment: "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id = 'bosted']/descendant::li[text() = '" + text + "']")).click();" resuls in: "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id = 'bosted']/descendant::li[text() = '" + text + "']")).click();".

Comment: "driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id='bosted' li[value=" + text + "]")).click();" resutls in: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score 0):

use the below customised xpath, it's almost as quick as using an id or a classname.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Leier kommunal bolig')]")).click();
```

Comment: This results in "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//fieldset[@id = 'bosted']/descendant::li[text() = 'Leier kommunal bolig']"}"

Comment: Can you open developer tool and search with //label[contains(text(),'Leier kommunal bolig')]  id you see results with 1/1, then the above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors do not allow to pick elements by inner text. Use XPath selector instead.

**P.S.** - If you still need to use the second option you should trim the text before comparing. Like `option.getText().trim().equals(bosituasjon)` because text in html might take tricky forms..

**P.P.S.** - If you think your second option is not still elegant enough you can apply steams api and make your code looking like this:

```
   List<WebElement> options = bosted.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
   options.stream().filter(i -> i.getText().trim().equals(bosituasjon)).findFirst().get().click();
```

Comment: But the problem is that the option IS a match - option.getText().equals(bosituasjon) is true. It's just that the click doesn't execute. Same thing when using stream().

Comment: Oh I see. Then try this `List<WebElement> options = bosted.findElements(By.xpath("//li/label"));`. If the element does not handle your click then it either has no associated handler. So I would try to click one level down or one level up (which seens not having sense in your case)

Comment: List<WebElement> options = bosted.findElements(By.xpath("//li/label")); results in "no value present" for the stream, btw.

Comment: Is this page a public one?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

There is No text option using css selector.You should use Xpath instead.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bosted']//li[contains(.,'" + text + "')]")).click()
```